# Select by Expression in QGIS Graphical Modeler on pre-defined layer name

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to build a model using the graphical model designer.

I have a conditional branch that loads a postgres layer depending on whether a "development" or "production" database is selected. I rename the final layer (called "5ghz_coverage") to be exactly the same, regardless of whether it comes from the dev or prod database, as any calculation from this point on is exactly the same.

However, when trying to select by expression, I don't want the input layer to be tied to the "dev" or "prod" output algorithm, as it may or may not be there. I don't want to have to duplicate every algorithm from here onward depending on which database was loaded from. I have been trying to use pre-calculated value for the input layer, but with no success.

I've tried creating a custom expression that returns a layer by the name. But when I run the model, it cannot find the field in the layer, even though it is the only field in the layer (other than id)

[image: model designer]

Custom Function:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def select_layer_by_name(layer_name):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    return layer
```

Select by expression configuration:
[image: select by expression configuration]

Error message when running model:

```
Prepare algorithm: qgis:selectbyexpression_1
Could not evaluate expression for parameter EXPRESSION for Select by expression: Field 'sector_name' not found
Execution failed after 1.34 seconds
```

Layer attributes:

[image: layer attributes]

How can I treat my postgres layers as 'the same' for all future algorithms in this model